# Is it possible to hide the header cell in a DataGridView for specific columns?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridcolumnheader, datagridviewimagecolumn

I have a `DataGridView` which is populated from a `DataTable`. I then supplement this with additional `DataGridViewImageColumn` which will ultimately function as buttons for manipulating the data on any given row.

What I want to know is, is it possible to hide the header cells for these image columns, but still retain them for the "data" columns (the image columns are the right-most columns in the grid) Either natively (the `.Visible` property of the individual image columns seems to be read-only?) or with some kind of funky workaround when painting the cells?

The buttons are relatively small but adding column headers (e.g. "Edit", "Delete" etc.) widens the columns unnecessarily and the images are (meant to be) self-explanatory as to what each one achieves. I also want to visually distinguish the data columns from the "action" columns. Yes, this is a purely aesthetic decision on my part!

Here is the code I am currently using to generate the `DataGridView` :

```
Dim myBindingSource As New BindingSource
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myBindingSource.Filter = myFilter
With myDataGridView
    .DataSource = myBindingSource 
    .AutoResizeColumns()
    .AutoResizeRows()
    .RowHeadersVisible = False
    .AllowUserToAddRows = False
    .Enabled = True
    
    btnEdit = New DataGridViewImageColumn With {.Image = icoEdit, .Width = 30}
    btnEdit.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(1, 1, 1, 1)
    .Columns.Insert(.Columns.Count, btnEdit)
    
    btnDelete = New DataGridViewImageColumn With {.Image = icoDelete, .Width = 30}
    btnDelete.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(1, 1, 1, 1)
    .Columns.Insert(.Columns.Count, btnDelete)
    
    btnCopy = New DataGridViewImageColumn With {.Image = icoCopy, .Width = 30}
    btnCopy.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(1, 1, 1, 1)
    .Columns.Insert(.Columns.Count, btnCopy)
    
    btnRestore = New DataGridViewImageColumn With {.Image = icoRestore, .Width = 30}
    btnRestore.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(1, 1, 1, 1)
    .Columns.Insert(.Columns.Count, btnRestore)
End With
```

Comment: Clear the `.HeaderText == "";` of these columns?

Comment: In WinForms, the `HeaderText` is displayed. If there is no `HeaderText`, then the `Name` is displayed instead. Since you didn't add any of them in the code above, the header cell should be empty. Btw, you can simply append the columns with `.Columns.Add(btnRestore)`.

Comment: Correct, I can clear the `.HeaderText` and `.Name` attributes, but I still end up with "blank" column headers and the border/outline of the header cell, which is "okay" but visually it looks like something is missing. I'd prefer to have the header cells for these columns as "dead space", similar to the surrounding areas outside the grid, if at all possible? I'm wondering if I can format them to "look" like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd prefer to have the header cells for these columns as "dead space", similar to the surrounding areas outside the grid...

Possible.

**VB.NET**

```vb
Private Sub myDataGridView_CellPainting(sender As Object,
    e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles myDataGridView.CellPainting

    Dim tarCols = {1, 2}

    If e.RowIndex = -1 AndAlso tarCols.Contains(e.ColumnIndex) Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.AppWorkspace, e.CellBounds)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**C#**

```cs
private void myDataGridView_CellPainting(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    var tarCols = new[] { 1, 2 };

    if (e.RowIndex == -1 && tarCols.Contains(e.ColumnIndex))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.AppWorkspace, e.CellBounds);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

In case you have a different `.BackgroundColor`:

**VB.NET**

```vb
Private Sub myDataGridView_CellPainting(sender As Object,
    e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles myDataGridView.CellPainting

    Dim tarCols = {1, 2}

    If e.RowIndex = -1 AndAlso tarCols.Contains(e.ColumnIndex) Then
        Using br = New SolidBrush(myDataGridView.BackgroundColor)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.CellBounds)
        End Using
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**C#**

```cs
private void myDataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    var tarCols = new[] { 1, 2 };

    if (e.RowIndex == -1 && tarCols.Contains(e.ColumnIndex))
    {
        using (var br = new SolidBrush(myDataGridView.BackgroundColor))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.CellBounds);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

[image: SO73635319]